# What's the proper tag for questions about differences between software editions?

Tags: discussion, tags

If somebody asks what are the differences between two editions of the same application, how should the question be tagged? For example [Difference between resin and resin pro](https://superuser.com/questions/104133/difference-between-resin-and-resin-pro) is currently [untagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and I have no idea what would be the proper tag, despite the question looking to me like it's on-topic.

Please note that a not-very-popular [windows-edition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-edition) tag already exists. Maybe it should be renamed to a more general [software-edition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-edition)?

Comment: My opinion is that those kinds of questions *should* be discouraged, in the sense most software has good changelogs that can be looked up online and most current software do very little in *removing* functionality from their programs. Besides, how many questions are there that ask for "differences between software versions"?. To tag those questions with [software-edition] would be, IMO, to tag questions that don't have any sort of relationship with one another, which is what tags are for.

Answer (score 8):

That question is now gone. As @Doktoro Reichard says, we actually discourage questions that ask for a general comparison between *X* and *Y*. Mostly because you could look up the differences yourself, and we'd found that those would also elicit opinion-based answers as well.

That being said, I could imagine a question asking how to solve  a specific problem you have with regard to different versions of an application, e.g. how to achieve something in a non-pro version, or asking about upgrade paths, et cetera.

There really should be no tag for this. If you compare software [a](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/a) and [b](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/b), then it should be tagged it with [a](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/a)[b](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/b).

Remember that tags are primarily meant for users who have a certain interest or expertise in a topic to find questions they can answer—but could there be an expert in [software-comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-comparison)? I highly doubt so.

Comment: But factual differences between characteristics/uses cases of a/b without going "it sux" would only change when they release a new version, no?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it should be much more specific than "List the differences between A and B".